Notification not getting fired from apex
I have added a component added on the community site that fetches details from an external system and fires a notification whenever the page loads. The response which I get as follows:
"custom": [
        {
            "customId": "QEW1112",
            "subject": "",
            "body": "testing may23"
        },
        {
            "customId": "IY4234",
            "subject": "subjectmay22",
            "body": "commentsmay22"
        }]

Based on this response I am creating a record in salesforce on a custom object and firing a notification on the same. I have mapped the notification title with the subject and body with the description but whenever the subject is blank from the external system notification is not getting fired but the records are getting created in Salesforce. For blank subject I am adding static value as title is mandatory for firing a notification.
Code Snippet:
//Parsing the response and storing in the object
    for(Broadcast broadcastObj : broadcastList){
    Notification__c notificationMessage = new Notification__c();                                                   
    notificationMessage.MessageId__c = broadcastObj.broadcastId;
    notificationMessage.Subject__c = broadcastObj.subject;
    notificationMessage.OrgId__c = orgId;
    notificationMessage.Description__c = broadcastObj.body;
    notificationMessage.Type__c = 'Broadcast';
    notificationList.add(notificationMessage); 
    }

if(notificationList?.size() > 0){
  insert notificationList;
}

if(notificationList?.size() > 0){
            try{
                System.debug('**********Notification List Size Insident Loop************' +notificationList.size());
                for(Notification_Message__c notificationMessageObj : notificationList){
                    String encodedBody =  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(notificationMessageObj.Description__c, 'UTF-8');
                    System.debug('***********************notificationMessageObj.Subject__c*****************'+ notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);
                    String subject = notificationMessageObj.Subject__c;
                    System.debug('******************subject*****************'+subject);
                    // if(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c == '' || notificationMessageObj.Subject__c == ' ' || notificationMessageObj.Subject__c == null){
                    if(String.isBlank(subject)){
                        notification.setTitle('Broadcast message');
                        System.debug('Notification Title Blank');
                    }
                    else{
                        notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);
                        System.debug('Notification Title Not Blank');
                    }
                    //notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);
                    notification.setBody(notificationMessageObj.Description__c);
                    notification.setNotificationTypeId(notificationType.Id);
                    Map<String, Object> pageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
                        'type' => 'standard__webPage',
                        'attributes' => new Map<String, Object> {
                            'url' => '/notification-detail?c__orgId='+orgId+ '&c__title='+notificationMessageObj.Subject__c+'&c__body='+encodedBody
                        }
                    };
                    notification.setTargetPageRef(JSON.serialize(pageRef));
                    notification.send(recipientIds);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Problem sending notification: ' + e.getMessage());
            } 
        }
    }



Does the notification.send line of code get executed? 2) what is the value of recipientIds?   3)  Pro tip: Checking for empty list before inserting is not required, you can insert collections of size 0 and not burn any DML limits.


Thanks for the tip @cropredy! I am adding the logged in user's Id in a set and using it in the recipient list. I have a similar array response from the same callout for which the notification is working. The issue occurs only when the subject is empty.

could this be the error: ...&c__title='+notificationMessageObj.Subject__c ... --shouldn't it be ... &c__title='+notification.getTitle() ...?

my bad @cropredy notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c) outside the if else block was deployed as uncommented which was causing the issue. This issue is now resolved. Thanks!

My changes were not getting reflected in the org.
Before Change:
if(String.isBlank(subject)){
                    notification.setTitle('Broadcast message');
                    System.debug('Notification Title Blank');
                }
                else{
                    notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);
                    System.debug('Notification Title Not Blank');
                }
  notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);

After change:
if(String.isBlank(subject)){
                        notification.setTitle('Broadcast message');
                        System.debug('Notification Title Blank');
                    }
                    else{
                        notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);
                        System.debug('Notification Title Not Blank');
                    }
                    //notification.setTitle(notificationMessageObj.Subject__c);

The commented line was not present in the org which was causing the issue.
